# Keep symbols when converting xcarchive to ipa

Tags: symbols, xcodebuild, bitcode, xcarchive

I am trying to rebuild bitcode files of a binary and during the process, clang displays an error about undefined symbols for architecture arm64 as the application makes use of external frameworks.

I noticed that if I provide the Frameworks folder in an xcarchive to the rebuilding process, clang can rebuild the bitcode files but if I use the Frameworks folder inside an ipa, I encounter the error about undefined symbols.

I am thinking that symbols for external frameworks would be removed when converting xcarchive to ipa. I compared the sizes of the dylibs and saw that the sizes are different.

Is there a way to specify that symbols for external frameworks be kept during the conversion process?

[EDIT]

I am trying to replicate what Apple would do when developers submit an IPA with bitcode enabled and it is able to rebuild versions of the application and install it in devices.

Currently, I am stuck at the xcarchive stage (not the final IPA) due to the symbols issues mentioned.